# Java Arraylist to Array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write a method using an `ArrayList` but I can't quite figure out how to do it.

I was able to do it with just using an array and I was wondering if there was an easy way to change it so that it does implement an `ArrayList`.

Here is my current code:

```
//public ArrayList<Integer> getPixelsInWindow(int wSize, int x, int y) {
//ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public int[] getPixelsInWindow(int wSize, int x, int y) {

    int [] values;

    int xMin = 0;
    int xMax = 0;
    int yMin = 0;
    int yMax = 0;

    xMin = x - (wSize / 2);
    if (xMin < 0)
        xMin = 0;
    yMin = y - (wSize / 2);
    if (yMin < 0)
        yMin = 0;   
    xMax = x + (wSize / 2);
    if (xMax >= rowN)
        xMax = rowN - 1;
    yMax = y + (wSize / 2);
    if (yMax >= columnN)
        yMax = columnN - 1;
    int differenceX = xMax-xMin;
    int differenceY = yMax-yMin;

    values = new int[(differenceX + 1)  * (differenceY + 1)];


    int j = 0;
    for(int i = xMin;i < xMax + 1;i++){
        for(int k = yMin;k < yMax + 1;k++){

            values[j] = img[i][k];
            if(j == 0){

            }
            j++;
        }
    }

    return values;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Where you assign the into *values* instead do list.add(Integer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was done quickly and not tested... but the idea is there, I am sure:

```
...
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();

int j = 0;
for(int i = xMin;i < xMax + 1;i++){
    for(int k = yMin;k < yMax + 1;k++){

        values.add(new Integer(img[i][k]));
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of "new Integer" I would use Integer.valueOf(...) which is the preferred way according to SUN practices (better in terms of memory management), or let auto-boxing do it for you. Also, no need for variable j anymore. But still +1